# How do I get .xcf files to open in GIMP instead of Inkscape by default?

Tags: gimp, default-programs, inkscape

For some reason, whenever I double-click a `.xcf` file in Nautilus or open it from the Dash, the file tries to load in Inkscape (with an error message) instead of in GIMP by default. I have both applications installed and I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

How do I get these files to open in GIMP by default instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the file go to properties, then "open" or "open with" (Haven't used GNOME in a while). Then choose GIMP as your standard and press ok.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a right click on that file, choose "properties" and then the tab "open with", there you can choose GIMP as standard application.